# Squat for over weight people

Tags: squats, dumbbells

I'm trying to do dumbbell squats but not possible. I feel unbalanced hence no confidence to put my weight on heels . Could anyone help me to find out how I could progress to there ? Is there way I can do some sort of variation, like beginner level to get there

Comment: Start light to get the right feel, that start going heavier if you feel more comfortable, really nothing else you can do. I guess you aren't doing with the barbell because you can not reach that far yet. Do some stretches to get there. In my opinion, squats with barbell are much better.

Answer (score 3):

You could try goblet squats, where you hold a single weight in front of you.

Or you could just to bodyweight squats, and work on getting low (ideally, you want to have your upper legs parallel to the ground or slightly lower. )

Comment: goblet squats worked ! , I managed to do two :) but I had to move weight some what away from the chest . Could this have negative effects ?

Comment: I think that is the point of the goblet squat. Your center of gravity should be directly above your feet. When you move the weight forward, you are "allowed" to move your body a bit backwards without falling.

Answer (score 1):

Beginner level is to start at a railing or counter that you can rest your fingers on as you squat to get comfortable with the maneuver. Stand close to a railing, begin with a slight hip hinge to get your hips behind you then begin to lower down. Start slowly lowering only slightly, feel your weight move into your heels, then push through your heels to stand. Get comfortable there then begin to go lower. When you are confident that you no longer need to hold on or be near support then step back and squat away from support. Then begin adding weights and just holding them at your sides. Progress from here. Have fun!